# Remove trailing "0d 0a" bytes from a file, using PowerShell

Tags: file, powershell, byte

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt files using PowerShell. In this case, I am working with .docx files. After encrypting the file, I passed it onto the decrypt function, and after decrypting it, the file is corrupted when trying to open.

However, after using a hex editor to compare both original and decrypted .docx files, the only difference is that the decrypted .docx file has 2 trailing bytes of "0d 0a".

I think this is the result of PowerShell's "Set-Content" command. 
(The Out-File command produces a far worse result.)

However, I am not able to just replace all the carriage return and line feed bytes as I would like to preserve the line feeds and carriage returns of the word document.

Is there a way I am able to remove only the trailing bytes of "0d 0a" of the decrypted and already-written .docx file?

Comment: `Set-Content -NoNewline`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve].

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks for answering, I am using PowerShell v2 which does not have the -NoNewline function, is there another way I could solve my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing your example its impossible to to tell where the extra CRLF is coming from. I would recommend examining your code to determine where it is coming from and then use an alternate route like the [System.IO.File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) class. If you are just looking for a quick solution you could read in the file and strip the last four bytes then output the byte array back to the same file overwriting it. This is a bandaid but should work.

```
#read in all contents
$bytes = [system.io.file]::ReadAllBytes("somefile.docx")
#write out all bytes except the last 4
#0 based so the last byte is at position length-1 then an additional 4 bytes
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes("somefile.docx",$bytes[0..($bytes.length-5)])
```

Comment: Thanks!!! This worked! But instead of -5, i changed it to -3, as -5 was removing 2 extra bytes.